# How can i retrieve the value from row that is text

Tags: php, mysql

here i am trying to retrieve the value from mysql table.
That value is of type text.but when i try to retrieve the value it is showing error.

error:

```
Could not get data: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'werc'
```

this is the code i have written.

```
<?php
    if(! $conn )
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT content FROM content';
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
    {
                echo $row['content'];
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: It is not related to any datatype of a column. But current database user has no access privilege to said database. Ask your DBA to grant permissions on that database.

Comment: there is no username given

Comment: @Dwza oh ok now i got it... i had given uname and password in config file. i had not given grant permission.

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql username or password is invalid. Make sure you have entered the correct mysql username and password in the connection string.

Comment: actually he has not given a usename at all^^

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your user has no rights to read data. It has nothing to do with your php source.